Help me recover my lost Bitcoin wallet
In 2015, I bought around 10 BTC at $400 each. I didn't realize I had them until one of these days, while going through my old Skype conversations with a friend, I found out that I had sold him a microphone in 2016, and he paid me with Crypto. That's how I remembered I had this wallet.
Unfortunately, I can't access my Bitcoins anymore. I had thrown away the laptop where I had them. I only have the Public Key and the wallet address.
Could someone please help me recover it?
Thank you.
